# Terminology in Kaplansky's book

Tags: commutative-algebra, terminology

In page 3 of the book Commutative Ring by Irving Kaplansky, the author states that:

> Let $R$ be any commutative ring, $A$ any nonzero $R$-module. The prime ideals maximal within the zero-divisor on $A$ are called the ***maximal primes***  of $A$.

I'm looking for nowaday name of the terminology ***maximal primes***.

Thank you.

Comment: I think a "maximal *associated* prime" of $A$ is what you're looking for. I'll try and list the relevant modern terminologies in an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm gonna list a few definitions in the modern language for my own sanity. The notation of $A$ for an $R$-module throws me off my game too much, so let me use $M$ instead. So the hypothesis is: $R$ is a commutative ring, $M$ is an $R$-module.

**Definition:** Let $a\in R$. We say $a$ is **$M$-regular** if the $R$-linear multiplication map $M\xrightarrow{a}M$ is injective. We call $a$ a **zero-divisor** of $M$ otherwise.

**Definition:** An **associated prime** of $M$ is a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subset R$ such that $\mathfrak{p}=\mathrm{Ann}(x)$ for some $x\in M$. The set of associated primes of $M$ is denoted by $\mathrm{Ass}(M)$.

**Proposition:** Let $\mathscr{S}$ be the set of all ideals of $R$ such that $\mathfrak{a}\in \mathscr{S}$ iff $\mathfrak{a}=\mathrm{Ann}(x)$ for some $0\neq x\in M$. An ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ which is maximal in $\mathscr{S}$ is a prime ideal.

If $\mathfrak{p}$ is an associated prime of $M$, then $\mathfrak{p}\in \mathscr{S}$, i.e. $\mathrm{Ass}(M)\subset \mathscr{S}$. At the same time let $Z(M)$ be the set of zero-divisors of $M$. Then $Z(M)=\bigcup \mathscr{S}$ is the union of all elements of $\mathscr{S}$. As a result what you are looking for, in this language, is simply a "maximal *associated* prime" of $M$.

**Side note:** If $R$ is furthermore Noetherian, then $\mathrm{Ass}(M)\neq \emptyset$ iff $M\neq 0$. In that case any ideal $\mathrm{Ann}(x)\in \mathscr{S}$ is contained in a maximal associated prime $\mathfrak{p}\in \mathrm{Ass}(M)$. This results in
$$
Z(M)=\bigcup_{\mathfrak{p}\in \mathrm{Ass}(M)}\mathfrak{p}
$$
All of this aside, however, I don't think the terminology of "maximal associated prime" is a very popular one in the literature. People just don't call this concept with any special name most of the time.

Comment: Thank you ! It' very helpful.

Comment: There is still a problem in your definition, kaplansky proved the complement of non-zero divisor is an union of primes for *general* commutative ring, these primes do not necessarily have form of $\mathrm{ann}(x)$.